# What is an equivalent of Mongodb .sort with several parameters in mongoosejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have collection foo:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076865a72da558dd40c819d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048494"), "a" : 2, "b" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048495"), "a" : 3, "b" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507686835c70b3b37c048496"), "a" : 0, "b" : 4 }
```

I want to sort it by `b`, then by `a`:

```
> db.foo.find().sort({b:-1,a:-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048495"), "a" : 3, "b" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076865a72da558dd40c819d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048494"), "a" : 2, "b" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507686835c70b3b37c048496"), "a" : 0, "b" : 4 }
```

Apparently, hash passed to sort() preserves the order of keys:

```
> db.foo.find().sort({a:-1,b:-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048495"), "a" : 3, "b" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076866f5c70b3b37c048494"), "a" : 2, "b" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5076865a72da558dd40c819d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507686835c70b3b37c048496"), "a" : 0, "b" : 4 }
```

What I need is to duplicate this behavior in Node.js application that uses mongoosejs as DB wrapper. I know that with one sorting parameter I can go with

```
Foo.find({},[],{sort:{b:-1}}, callback)
```

Having two parameters confuses me as both `Foo.find({},[],{sort:{b:-1, a:-1}}, callback)` and `Foo.find({},[],{sort:{a:-1, b:-1}}, callback)` return the elements in the same order (sorted by `a`) - as it should, as obviously hashes/objects have no key order.

I know that you can pass arrays(e.g. `['b','a']`), but am still unsure how to set reverse order: `['-b','-a']`, although being recoginzed by mongoosejs, sorts in direct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongoose 3.x you can pass a string into [Query#sort](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) to do this:

```js
Foo.find().sort('-b -a').exec(callback);
```